# E: Невозможно найти пакет (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Решил я попробовать и вкусить жизнь на линуксе . Сделал загрузчик , установил и решил поставить пару библиотек  для ***PYTHON*** . При загрузки библиотек выдаёт эту ошибку ***`E: Невозможно найти пакет`*** . Библиотеку ставил beautifulsoup4 . (Обновлял пакеты и т.д ничего не помогает)

Comment: А почему вы решили, что интересующие вас пакеты в принципе должны быть в линуксовых репозиториях? И почему бы их не установить из PyPI через обычный pip install?

Comment: Ну а вообще в Ubuntu этот пакет правильно называется `python3-bs4`